# Pass variable text to src in swift

Tags: swift2

Trying to pass the variable from a text input on viewcontroller.swift to a second view page (view2). Having trouble with string() as an input. Here's what I have:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class View2 : UIViewController {

    var PlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var PlayerView = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    let fileURL = NSURL (fileURLWithPath: String())
    PlayerView = AVPlayer (URL: srcURL)
    PlayerViewController.player = PlayerView

    self.presentViewController(PlayerViewController, animated: true){
        self.PlayerViewController.player?.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all: variable names (unlike class names) are supposed to start with a lowercase letter for better readability. Second of all: You can't initialize a view controller with the default initializer `()`. Third of all: You can't execute code like `self.presentViewController(...` outside a method.

Answer (score 0):

Drag your TextView from storyboard to your View Controller swift file as an Outlet

and give it a name for example

```
@IBOutlet weak var texty: UITextField!
```

and then set a variable for example

```
var yourTexty: String!
```

and then you do

```
yourTexty = texty.text
```